# How to convert nepali date of database in to english date?

Tags: mysql

Can any one guide me how to convert the nepali date of database in to english date.

Database is here:

```
id  date
1   2071/12/21
2   2071/9/15
```

Comment: no i dont want output. i want the process to convert this database date into english date

Comment: what is Your expected Format of the date?

Comment: 2014/8/13 this is what i want

Comment: Plz elaborate the your format. How is the date and month are coming?

Comment: year/month/day this is what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as far as the formula itself goes, it's described here: 
http://www.mypatro.com/date-converter.html

If you tell us what language are you trying to convert it in (programming language and \ or SQL dialect, such as MySQL, MSSQL etc) I can try and help converting the formula to an actual code.

EDIT:

Assuming $result contains your sql results;

```
$formatted_data = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $nepali_date = strtotime($row['date']);
    $english_date = strtotime("-56 years 8 months 16 days",$nepali_date)
    $formatted_data['english_date'] = $english_date;
}
```

Comment: The language i am using is postgresql, but i want to convert using php

Comment: Thank you: $date['age'] = date("Y/m/d",$english_date);

Answer (score 0):

To make an approximate conversion, subtract 56 Years, 8 Months and 16 Days:

```
select
    id,
    date - interval '56 year' 
         - interval '8 month'
         - interval '16 day' as date
from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Again converting the strotime in to formated date:

```
$date['age'] = date("Y/m/d",$english_date);
```